# Remove and edit items in knockout observableArray

Tags: javascript, mvvm, view, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have an array `exercises` inside observableArray `workouts`. I want to add the ability to remove items from it. Tried to make it an observableArray:

```
self.exercises = ko.observableArray();
```

and added a function to remove items:

```
self.removeExercise = function() {
        self.exercises.remove(this);
    };
```

But nothing happens. While the same function works with `workouts` parent array.
Along with this I have a simple function for editing items in array, which looks like this:

```
this.edit = function() { this.editing(true) }
```

And try to bind it in my View:

```
<span data-bind="text: name, click: edit"> </span>
```

but it doesn't work. Where the problem can be?

Here's my View

```
<div class="content">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: workouts">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: name, click: edit"> </span>
                 <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeWorkout">Remove</a>
             <ul data-bind="foreach: exercises">
                 <li>
                     <span data-bind="text: name"> </span>
                     <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeExercise">remove</a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

And ViewModel:

```
function AppViewModel() {   
    var self = this;

    self.workouts = ko.observableArray([
    {name: "Workout1", exercises:[
        { name: "Exercise1.1" },
        { name: "Exercise1.2" },
        { name: "Exercise1.3" }
    ]},
]);

    self.exercises = ko.observableArray();

    self.removeWorkout = function() {
        self.workouts.remove(this);
    };
    self.removeExercise = function() {
        self.exercises.remove(this);
    };

    this.editing = ko.observable(false);
    this.edit = function() { this.editing(true) }    
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel);
```

Here's an example on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/c9fQB/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bindingContext should be $root for removeExercise, and exercises should be an observableArray. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ag8rr/

The observables code:

```
    self.exercises = ko.observableArray([
        { name: "Exercise1.1" },
        { name: "Exercise1.2" },
        { name: "Exercise1.3" }
    ]);    

    self.workouts = ko.observableArray([
    {name: "Workout1", exercises:self.exercises},
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I've got the idea. But how can I enable editing then?

Comment: Yes, but don't need an input field, just to click on exercise or workout name and it should become editable, then click elsewhere and apply changes.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I'll try to understand everything in code :)
So you made a function constructor `Record`, then you make new object with this function `new Record("Exercise1.1")`?

Comment: Yup, exactly, since the Record code can become quite complicated, it's easier to have it in a separate function. Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it was useful.

Comment: I'm sorry to trouble you, but could you please help how to add not all 3 exercises to workouts array, but only two, for example? The idea is that I have many workouts, and each of them should have its specific exercises. So rather than make a new array of exercises for each workout, it's better to keep all exercises in one array, and add to workouts only the needed ones(by indexes or how?).

Comment: This should be a helpful example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/UdXr4/ The full article:  http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/02/revisiting-dragging-dropping-and.html

Comment: Could you tell me how can I get the name value of first exercise here? http://jsfiddle.net/Zp4K8/
You helped me earlier and used a new Record function to create objects.
I'm a bit confused because of that Record constructor.

Comment: Well, just do self.exercises()[0].name()

Comment: Thank you very much. Forgot about brackets after name